# Sequelize Many to Many - Updating associations table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building an app using Sequelize with Node.js where I have a Product model and a Category model.

A product can have many Categories, and a category can have many products.
And I'd like to update the associations (adding and removing categories of a product)
How can I update the association table?

```
db.Product.find({
  where: {
    id: 1
  }
}).then((res) => {
  //  Updating associations table HERE
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm assuming you have an association definition like this:

```
Product.belongsToMany(Category,
  { through: ProductCategory, foreignKey: 'productId', otherKey: 'categoryId' })
```

```
//  Updating associations table HERE
res.addCategories(categories).then(x => {
// categories added successfully to the product
})
```